# "Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed" when using tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have tensorflow 1.14 and I want to compute some classification metrics.

I am using `tf.keras.metrics` and I am using it in the follwoing manner:

```
tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(support_pred, dim=1), axis=1),
                                                   tf.argmax(support_y, axis=1))
```

This gives me the error:

> {TypeError}Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

I tried to use instead `tf.contrib.metrics` but it only has `precision_at_recall` and `recall_at_precision` instead of stand alone precision and recall.

**EDIT 1**

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random.uniform((32, 10), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random.uniform((32, 10), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)

a_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(a)
b_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(b)

a_argmax = tf.argmax(a_softmax, axis=-1)
b_argmax = tf.argmax(b_softmax, axis=-1)

acc = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()(a_argmax, b_argmax)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([acc])
```

It gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/total)
     [[{{node AssignAddVariableOp}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/96171/Desktop/dementia_cleanedup/dementia/maml_finn_copy/try_tf.py", line 15, in <module>
    sess.run(acc)
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/total)
     [[node AssignAddVariableOp (defined at /Users/96171/Desktop/dementia_cleanedup/dementia/maml_finn_copy/try_tf.py:12) ]]

Original stack trace for 'AssignAddVariableOp':
  File "/Users/96171/Desktop/dementia_cleanedup/dementia/maml_finn_copy/try_tf.py", line 12, in <module>
    acc = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()(a_argmax, b_argmax)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 170, in __call__
    update_op = self.update_state(*args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 73, in decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 551, in update_state
    matches, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 314, in update_state
    update_total_op = self.total.assign_add(value_sum)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1108, in assign_add
    name=name)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_resource_variable_ops.py", line 68, in assign_add_variable_op
    "AssignAddVariableOp", resource=resource, value=value, name=name)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`tf.metrics.Accuracy` creates an object with a state that is usually updated several times. So it can't be called with `y_pred` and `y_true`. Try:

```
tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(support_pred, dim=1), axis=1),
                                                   tf.argmax(support_y, axis=1))
```

It works if you have the `argmax` of the `softmax` of both your output and the labels:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(0)

a = tf.random.uniform((32, 10), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random.uniform((32, 10), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)

a_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(a)
b_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(b)

a_argmax = tf.argmax(a_softmax, axis=-1)
b_argmax = tf.argmax(b_softmax, axis=-1)

tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()(a_argmax, b_argmax)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.1875>
```

Comment: It works indeed. Thank you so much!! @Nicolos Gervais

Comment: Could you please check the edit ? I though it worked but it did not :(

Comment: I have no idea what this is. It doesn't seem related to your original issue

Comment: Yes but turned out that ```tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()(a_argmax, b_argmax)``` is not working. That's why I updated it :(

Comment: That's simple Tensorflow code, maybe your Tensorflow build is broken? I'm looking at the traceback and it doesn't refer to a problem in this operation. And it worked yesterday?

Comment: It did work at comiplation, but at runtime when I was calling it from ```sess.run([])```it was giving me a ```FailedPreConditionErrror``` that the variable is not found, but when I use ```tf.contrib.metrics``` it does not show the error, but I do not want to use ```contrib``` because it does not support the ```precision``` calculation the way I want it

Comment: You can unmark this question as solved, perhaps someone else will provide an answer. I've never used TF1.X